# How to extract second largest value via Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator

I am trying to find the largest and the second largest value in a row from my shapefield table. The largest is easy to find with the `max()` expression. The second largest is quite easy to find in Python via:

```
a = [VALUE_1,VALUE_2,VALUE_3,VALUE_4,VALUE_5]
a.sort()
print a[-2]
```

If I use the same code in the field calculator I get the message that VALUE_1 is not defined. But I stated the input in the expression.

[image]

Comment: Can you screenshot your field calculator input? Hard to debug without seeing it.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include multiple columns or multiple rows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a Search Cursor to find the values in your field, and then return the two highest values through the Field Calculator

In the Pre-logic script code:

```
vals = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("testPoint", ['intfield']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        vals.append(row[0])
vals.sort()

def maxvals(fieldval):
    global vals
    if fieldval in vals:
        if fieldval in [vals[-1], vals[-2]] :
            return fieldval
```

And in the expression:

```
maxvals( !intfield!)
```

Where `!intfield!` is the name of the field you want to search in, and `"testPoint"` is the name of your layer

In Field Calculator window:
[image]

In Calculate Field geoprocessing tool:
[image]

And the result:
[image]

---

Upon re-reading your question, it sounds like you want to look across multiple fields to find the max and next values.

Max Value Pre-logic code:

```
def maxnum(fields):
    fields.sort()
    return fields[-1]
```

Second-max Value Pre-logic code:

```
def maxnum(fields):
    fields.sort()
    return fields[-2]
```

Expression:

```
maxnum([!intfield!, !intfield2!, !intfield3!, !intfield4!])
```

Pass your fields as a list here in your expression.

Field Calculator window:
[image]

Calculate Field:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your codeblock to something like:

```
def a(VALUE_1,VALUE_2,VALUE_3):
    vals = [VALUE_1,VALUE_2,VALUE_3]
    vals.sort()
    return vals[0]
```

It would be better practice to rewrite the expression as something like:

```
getMax(!VALUE_1!,!VALUE_2!,!VALUE_3!)
```

And change your codeblock to:

```
def getMax(VALUE_1,VALUE_2,VALUE_3):
        vals = [VALUE_1,VALUE_2,VALUE_3]
        vals.sort()
        return vals[0]
```

Bear in mind this only returns the max value, if you want the second largest value, use `return vals[1]`, or if you want the sum of the largest and second largest, use `return vals[0] + vals[1]`

Comment: Just realised Midavolo's answer includes a slightly more concise version of this answer - use that!